# Вызов метода родительского класса PyQT

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, pyside6

Есть некая программа с **`2`**-мя окнами:

- 1-е главное окно (`main`) где всё отображается;
- 2-е окно добавления заметок (`AddNotesForm`).

Так вот я никак не могу понять принцип работы сигналов и слотов. 
Как сделать так, чтобы при закрытии дочернего окна (`AddNotesForm`) по крестику или кнопке, вызывался метод родительского окна (`main`) "обновление информации после добавления"?

Пробовал разные варианты и практически всегда получаю ошибки типа:

> "AttributeError: object has no attribute".

Main

```
import sys
from PySide6 import *

# ----- Импорт форм и стилей
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PySide6.QtCore import QSortFilterProxyModel, Qt
from PySide6.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QToolBar, QHeaderView

from gui_MainWindow_Notes import Ui_MainWindow
from settingsForm import SettingsForm
from addToolboxForm import AddNotesForm
from imagesForNote import ImagesForNote
from utilsCommunalPaymentDialog import UtilsCommunalPayment
from synchronizedForm import SynchronizedFormForm

# ----- Импорт для работы с config.ini
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini', encoding='utf-8-sig')

# ----- Импорт для работы с базой данных
from db import DbWork as dbexec

# ----- Импорт дополнительных функций и констант
from functions.Extensions import Extensions


class MainApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
# ----- Конструктор класса
    def __init__(self, name='admin'):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  # Создание формы и Ui (наш дизайн)
        self.showMaximized()  # Показать наше окно на весь экран

        self.createToolBarTextEditNote()
        self.database = config["db"]["db_select"]

        self.settingsWindow_action.triggered.connect(self.settingsDialog)  # Запуск окна настроек по клику в menubar
        self.exitApp_action.triggered.connect(self.exitProgramm)  # Закрытие программы по клику в menubar

        if self.database == "mysql":
            self.connect = dbexec.create_connection_mysql(self)
        elif self.database == "sqlite3" or self.database == "all":
            self.connect = dbexec.create_connection_sqlite(self)
        if self.connect == None:
            mess = Extensions.showMessageBoxYesNo(self, "Соединение с БД", "Нет соединения c БД MySQL! \n Проверьте настройки подключения или переключитесь на другую БД. \n Переключиться?")
            if mess == 1024:
                self.settingsDialog()
            else:
                pass
        else:
            self.init_all()

        self.tableView_Books.clicked.connect(self.selectedBooks) # Клик по книге (1 таблица) и вывод заметок (2 таблица)
        self.tableView_Notes.clicked.connect(self.selectedNote) # Клик по заметке (2 таблица) и вывод содержимого заметки (textEdit_Notes)

        self.textEdit_Notes.textChanged.connect(self.pushButton_saveNoteTextEdit.setEnabled(True)) # После
        self.lineEdit_searchBooks.textChanged.connect(self.searchBook)
        self.lineEdit_searchNote.textChanged.connect(self.searchNote)

        self.comboBox_choiseBookForNote.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.on_combobox_changed)

        self.lineEdit_titleNote.setText("")
        self.textEdit_Notes.setText("")
        self.label_NoteIdHidden.setText("")

    def init_all(self):
        self.loadDataAll()  # Загрузка разделов заметок в левую таблицу при запуске программы
        self.searchNote("")  # Загрузка заметок в среднюю таблицу при запуске программы
        self.pushButton_reloadAllMainDataWindow.clicked.connect(self.loadDataAll)  # Обновление данных главного окна
        self.pushButton_addNewNotes_Left.clicked.connect(self.addNotesDialog)  # Запуск окна добавления разделов и заметок
        self.utilsCommunalPaymentWindow_action.triggered.connect(self.utilsCommunalPaymentDialog)  # Запуск окна утилиты/ЖКХ по клику в menubar
        self.pushButton_imagesForNote.clicked.connect(self.imgForNote)  # Запуск окна добавления или редактирования изображений для заметки
        self.pushButton_syncDB.clicked.connect(self.syncDbForProgramm)  # Запуск окна синхронизации
        self.pushButton_deleteNoteTextEdit.clicked.connect(self.deleteNote)  # Запуск окна добавления разделов и заметок
        self.pushButton_saveNoteTextEdit.clicked.connect(self.changeNoteAndSave)  # Сохранение заметки после редактирования
        self.pushButton_deleteBook.clicked.connect(self.deleteBook)  # Удаление раздела

    def on_combobox_changed(self, value):
        self.selectBook = self.comboBox_choiseBookForNote.currentIndex() # ID Выбранной книги
        self.comboBox_choiseBookForNote.itemData(self.comboBox_choiseBookForNote.currentIndex())  # ID Выбранной книги для смены книги у выбранной заметки comboboks справа

# ----- Инициализация окна настроек
    def settingsDialog(self):
        self.w2 = SettingsForm(self)
        self.w2.show()

# ----- Инициализация окна добавления заметок
    def addNotesDialog(self):
        self.w3 = AddNotesForm(self)
        self.w3.show()

# ----- Инициализация окна утилиты/ЖКХ
    def utilsCommunalPaymentDialog(self):
        self.w4 = UtilsCommunalPayment(self)
        self.w4.show()

# ----- Инициализация окна утилиты/ЖКХ
    def syncDbForProgramm(self):
        self.w5 = SynchronizedFormForm(self)
        self.w5.show()

######### Тестовая функция
    def clickCloseSubWindow(*args):
        print("Дочернее окно закрыто")


    def loadDataAll(self):
        print("reload")
        if self.database == "mysql":
            connect = dbexec.create_connection_mysql(self)
            sql = "SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY book_title DESC"
            rowBooks = dbexec.execute_read_query_mysql(self, connect, sql)

        elif self.database == "sqlite3" or self.database == "all":
            connect = dbexec.create_connection_sqlite(self)
            sql = "SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY book_title DESC"
            rowBooks = dbexec.execute_read_query_sqlite(self, connect, sql)

        model = QStandardItemModel(len(rowBooks), 1)
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['ID', 'Разделы'])
        for row, book in enumerate(rowBooks):
            model.setItem(row, 0, QStandardItem(str(book[0])))
            model.setItem(row, 1, QStandardItem(str(book[1])))

        filter_proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        filter_proxy_model.setSourceModel(model)
        filter_proxy_model.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        filter_proxy_model.setFilterKeyColumn(0)

        self.tableView_Books.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.tableView_Books.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.tableView_Books.setModel(filter_proxy_model)
        self.tableView_Books.setColumnHidden(0, True)
        self.tableView_Books.setAlternatingRowColors(True)

        for item_book in rowBooks:
            self.comboBox_choiseBookForNote.addItem(item_book[1], item_book[0])
        self.lineEdit_titleNote.setText("")
        self.textEdit_Notes.setText("")
        self.label_NoteIdHidden.setText("")

        # self.tableView_Notes.setRowCount(0)
        index = self.tableView_Books.currentIndex()
        row = index.row()
        index = self.tableView_Books.model().index(row, 0)
        self.idBook = str(self.tableView_Books.model().data(index))

        if self.database == "mysql":
            connect = dbexec.create_connection_mysql(self)
            sql = "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE note_parent = " + self.idBook + ""
            rowNote = dbexec.execute_read_query_mysql(self, connect, sql)

        elif self.database == "sqlite3" or self.database == "all":
            connect = dbexec.create_connection_sqlite(self)
            sql = "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE note_parent = " + self.idBook + ""
            rowNote = dbexec.execute_read_query_sqlite(self, connect, sql)

        model = QStandardItemModel(len(rowNote), 1)
        for row, book in enumerate(rowNote):
            model.setItem(row, 0, QStandardItem(str(book[0])))
            model.setItem(row, 1, QStandardItem(str(book[1])))

        filter_proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        filter_proxy_model.setSourceModel(model)
        filter_proxy_model.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        filter_proxy_model.setFilterKeyColumn(0)

        self.tableView_Notes.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.tableView_Notes.horizontalHeader().hide()
        self.tableView_Notes.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.tableView_Notes.setModel(filter_proxy_model)
        self.tableView_Notes.setColumnHidden(0, True)
        self.tableView_Notes.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        index = self.tableView_Notes.currentIndex()
        row = index.row()
        index = self.tableView_Notes.model().index(row, 0)
        noteId = self.tableView_Notes.model().data(index)

        if self.database == "mysql":
            connect = dbexec.create_connection_mysql(self)
            sql = "SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM images WHERE images.img_id_note = notes.note_id) as count, notes.*, books.book_title FROM notes LEFT JOIN books on books.book_id = notes.note_parent WHERE notes.note_id = " + noteId + ""
            rowPage = dbexec.execute_read_query_mysql(self, connect, sql)

        elif self.database == "sqlite3" or self.database == "all":
            connect = dbexec.create_connection_sqlite(self)
            sql = "SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM images WHERE images.img_id_note = notes.note_id) as count, notes.*, books.book_title FROM notes LEFT JOIN books on books.book_id = notes.note_parent WHERE notes.note_id = " + noteId + ""
            rowPage = dbexec.execute_read_query_sqlite(self, connect, sql)

        index = self.comboBox_choiseBookForNote.findText(rowPage[0][6], QtCore.Qt.MatchFixedString)
        if index >= 0:
            self.comboBox_choiseBookForNote.setCurrentIndex(index)

        for item in rowPage:
            self.lineEdit_titleNote.setText(str(item[2]))
            self.textEdit_Notes.setText(item[3])
        self.pushButton_imagesForNote.setText("Изображения ( " + str(item[0]) + " )")
        self.label_NoteIdHidden.setText(str(item[1]))  # Устанеавливаем ID в скрытый лэйбл для сохранения, удаления или изображений

    def createToolBarTextEditNote(self):
        tool = QToolBar()
        tool.addWidget(self.pushButton_undo_toolbar)
        tool.addWidget(self.pushButton_repeat_toolbar)
        self.toolBox_horizontalLayout.addWidget(tool)
        search_text = search_text.upper()
        if self.database == "mysql":
            connect = dbexec.create_connection_mysql(self)
            sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE book_search LIKE '%{}%' ORDER BY book_title DESC".format(search_text)
            rowBooks = dbexec.execute_read_query_mysql(self, connect, sql)

        elif self.database == "sqlite3" or self.database == "all":
            connect = dbexec.create_connection_sqlite(self)
            sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE book_search LIKE '%{}%' ORDER BY book_title DESC".format(search_text)
            rowBooks = dbexec.execute_read_query_sqlite(self, connect, sql)

        model = QStandardItemModel(len(rowBooks), 1)
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['ID', 'Заметки'])
        for row, book in enumerate(rowBooks):
            model.setItem(row, 0, QStandardItem(str(book[0])))
            model.setItem(row, 1, QStandardItem(str(book[1])))

        filter_proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        filter_proxy_model.setSourceModel(model)
        filter_proxy_model.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        filter_proxy_model.setFilterKeyColumn(-1)

        search_field = self.lineEdit_searchBooks
        search_field.textChanged.connect(filter_proxy_model.setFilterRegularExpression)
        self.tableView_Books.setModel(filter_proxy_model)

        self.tableView_Books.setColumnHidden(0, Tru
        if self.database == "mysql":
            connect = dbexec.create_connection_mysql(self)
            sql = "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE note_search LIKE '%{}%' ORDER BY note_title DESC".format(search_text.upper())
            rowPage = dbexec.execute_read_query_mysql(self, connect, sql)

        elif self.database == "sqlite3" or self.database == "all":
            connect = dbexec.create_connection_sqlite(self)
            sql = "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE note_search LIKE '%{}%' ORDER BY note_title DESC".format(search_text.upper())
            rowPage = dbexec.execute_read_query_sqlite(self, connect, sql)

        model = QStandardItemModel(len(rowPage), 1)
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['ID', 'Заметки'])
        for row, note in enumerate(rowPage):
            model.setItem(row, 0, QStandardItem(str(note[0])))
            model.setItem(row, 1, QStandardItem(str(note[1])))

        filter_proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        filter_proxy_model.setSourceModel(model)
        filter_proxy_model.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        filter_proxy_model.setFilterKeyColumn(-1)

        self.tableView_Notes.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.tableView_Notes.horizontalHeader().hide()
        self.tableView_Notes.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        search_field = self.lineEdit_searchBooks
        search_field.textChanged.connect(filter_proxy_model.setFilterRegularExpression)
        self.tableView_Notes.setModel(filter_proxy_model)
        self.tableView_Notes.setColumnHidden(0, True)

    def exitProgramm(self):
        sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    omstools = MainApp()
    app.exec()
```

AddNotesForm

```
#import uuid
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from gui_AddToolboxWindow_Notes import Ui_AddToolboxWindow
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini', encoding='utf-8-sig')
from db import DbWork as dbexec
from functions.Extensions import Extensions

class AddNotesForm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_AddToolboxWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent, QtCore.Qt.Window)
        self.setupUi(self)  # Создание формы и Ui (наш дизайн)
        self.show()  # Показать наше окно
        self.parrent = self.parent()

        self.loadData()

        self.saveBook_toolBox_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.addNewBook)
        self.savePage_toolBox_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.addNewPage)
        self.cancelAddBook_toolBox_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.destroy_window)
        self.cancelAddPage_toolBox_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.destroy_window)
        
    def loadData(self):

        database = config["db"]["db_select"]
        if database == "mysql":
            connect = dbexec.create_connection_mysql(self)
            sql = "SELECT * FROM books"
            result = dbexec.execute_read_query_mysql(self, connect, sql)

        elif database == "sqlite3" or database == "all":
            connect = dbexec.create_connection_sqlite(self)
            sql = "SELECT * FROM books"
            result = dbexec.execute_read_query_sqlite(self, connect, sql)

        for item in result:
            self.selectBook_addPage_toolBox_comboBox.addItem(item[1], item[0])

    def addNewBook(self):
        if not self.addBook_toolBox_lineEdit.text():
            Extensions.showMessageBox(self, 'Ошибка', 'Необходимо заполнить все поля!')
            pass
        else:
            database = config["db"]["db_select"]
            #uuid_code = uuid.uuid4().hex
            if database == "mysql":
                connect = dbexec.create_connection_mysql(self)
                sql = """INSERT INTO books (book_title, book_search) VALUES ('{}', '{}')""".format(self.addBook_toolBox_lineEdit.text(), self.addBook_toolBox_lineEdit.text().upper())
                dbexec.execute_query_mysql(self, connect, sql)
                prefix = "sqlite3"
                dbexec.uniq_filename_sql(self, prefix, sql)

                dbexec.sync_sql_execute(self, prefix, sql, Extensions.BOOK_PRIORITY)

            elif database == "sqlite3" or database == "all":
                connect = dbexec.create_connection_sqlite(self)
                sql = """INSERT INTO books (book_title, book_search) VALUES ('{}', '{}')""".format(self.addBook_toolBox_lineEdit.text(), self.addBook_toolBox_lineEdit.text().upper())
                dbexec.execute_query_sqlite(self, connect, sql)
                prefix = "mysql"
                dbexec.uniq_filename_sql(self, prefix, sql)

                dbexec.sync_sql_execute(self, prefix, sql, Extensions.BOOK_PRIORITY)

            self.addBookSuccess_label.setText('Книга успешно добавлена!')
        self.loadData()

    def addNewPage(self):
        noteTitle = self.addPage_toolBox_lineEdit.text()
        selectBook = self.selectBook_addPage_toolBox_comboBox.itemData(self.selectBook_addPage_toolBox_comboBox.currentIndex())
        noteText = self.addPageText_toolBox_textEdit.toPlainText()

        if not noteTitle or selectBook is None:
            Extensions.showMessageBox(self, 'Ошибка', 'Необходимо заполнить все поля!')
            pass
        else:
            database = config["db"]["db_select"]
            if database == "mysql":
                connect = dbexec.create_connection_mysql(self)
                sql = """INSERT INTO `notes` (`note_title`, `note_text`, `note_parent`, `note_search`) VALUES ('{}', '{}', {}, '{}');""".format(noteTitle, noteText, selectBook, noteTitle.upper() + " " + noteText.upper())
                dbexec.execute_query_mysql(self, connect, sql)
                prefix = "sqlite3"
                dbexec.uniq_filename_sql(self, prefix, sql)

                dbexec.sync_sql_execute(self, prefix, sql, Extensions.NOTE_PRIORITY)

            elif database == "sqlite3" or database == "all":
                connect = dbexec.create_connection_sqlite(self)
                sql = """INSERT INTO `notes` (`note_title`, `note_text`, `note_parent`, `note_search`) VALUES ('{}', '{}', {}, '{}');""".format(noteTitle, noteText, selectBook, noteTitle.upper() + " " + noteText.upper())
                dbexec.execute_query_sqlite(self, connect, sql)
                prefix = "mysql"
                dbexec.uniq_filename_sql(self, prefix, sql)

                dbexec.sync_sql_execute(self, prefix, sql, Extensions.NOTE_PRIORITY)

            self.addPageSuccess_label.setText('Заметка успешно добавлена!')


    def destroy_window(self):
        print("destroy_window")
        self.parent.init_all
        self.close()


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.parent.init_all
        print("closeEvent")
```

Comment: Для этого используют конструкцию super().func()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я совсем недавно более подробно описывал принципы работы сигналов и слотов. Вы можете найти это описание в моих ответах.

```
class AddNotesForm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
#    signal_close_notes_form = Signal()                         # PySide6    # <---- 
    signal_close_notes_form = pyqtSignal()                      # PyQt5    

    ...

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print("\ncloseEvent") 
        self.signal_close_notes_form.emit()                             # <----
```

---

```
class MainApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, name='admin'):
        super().__init__()

    ...

        self.w3 = AddNotesForm(self)
        self.w3.signal_close_notes_form.connect(self.loadDataAll)           # <---- 

    ...

    def loadDataAll(self):                                                  # <---- 
        # Вывод разделов заметок в ...
        print("reload")
```

---

---

**q1469645_main.py**

```
import sys
# установите свои импорты PySide6                               # !!!
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtTest  
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from q1469645_addToolboxForm import AddNotesForm


class MainApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, name='admin'):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('MainApp', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        self.pushButton_reloadAllMainDataWindow = QPushButton()
        self.pushButton_reloadAllMainDataWindow.setText('Обновление данных главного окна')
        # Обновление данных главного окна
        self.pushButton_reloadAllMainDataWindow.clicked.connect(self.loadDataAll)  
    
        pushButton = QPushButton('Показать AddNotesForm')
        pushButton.clicked.connect(self.addNotesDialog)
        
        layout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget) 
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton_reloadAllMainDataWindow, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(pushButton, 1, 1)
        
        self.w3 = AddNotesForm(self)
        self.w3.signal_close_notes_form.connect(self.loadDataAll)           # <---- 

    def addNotesDialog(self):
        self.w3.show()        

    def loadDataAll(self):                                                  # <---- 
        # Вывод разделов заметок в ...
        print("reload")
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    omstools = MainApp()
    omstools.show()
    app.exec()
```

**q1469645_addToolboxForm.py**

```
import sys
# установите свои импорты PySide6                               # !!!
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtTest  
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class AddNotesForm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
#    signal_close_notes_form = Signal()                         # PySide6    # <---- 
    signal_close_notes_form = pyqtSignal()                      # PyQt5      
    

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent, QtCore.Qt.Window)

#        self.parrent = self.parent()
#        print(f'{parent}')  
#        print(f'{self.parrent}')  
        
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('AddNotesForm', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        self.cancelAddPage_toolBox_pushButton = QPushButton()
        self.cancelAddPage_toolBox_pushButton.setText('Обновление данных главного окна')
        # Обновление данных главного окна
        self.cancelAddPage_toolBox_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)  
        
        layout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget) 
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.cancelAddPage_toolBox_pushButton, 1, 0)
      
        

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print("\ncloseEvent") 
        self.signal_close_notes_form.emit()                             # <----
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да, чуть не забыл, вы должны научиться составлять минимально-воспроизводимые примеры, которые демонстрируют только суть проблемы, а не работу с БД.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо большое за ответ! Сделал всё как вы доходчего разъеснили, но вылетает ошибка `"TypeError: AddNotesForm cannot be converted to PyQt5.QtCore.QObject in this context"`

Comment: @Михаил вы запускали мой пример, в котором `убрали импорты PyQt5` и `установили свои импорты для PySide6` ?

Comment: Да, конечно запускал. Ваш пример работает отлично!  Когда перенёс в свой проект смутила ошибка. Но видимо был конфликт с `from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtCore`. Когда поменял `signal_close_notes_form = pyqtSignal()` на `signal_close_notes_form = Signal()`, то всё заработало! Спасибо Вам огромное!

Comment: И можно вопрос не по теме? При использовании события `closeEvent` (нажатие на крестик окна) 1-й раз окно закрывается нормально, 2-й раз окно как будто открывается и закрывается дважды, 3-й раз окно как будто открывается и закрывается трижды и так с нарастающим, что может быть?

Comment: @Михаил пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour  Если у вас возникают другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос. То что вы описываете, говорит о том, что вы не в том месте делаете привязку сигнала и слота. Смотрите внимательно что и где делается в моем примере.

Comment: Спасибо, большое! Сделал как вы сказали. Попробую разобраться сам.